# Vertices are double of edges

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to detect the communities in a temporal network, that is, i want to detect communities at different time stamp and for that I am using Dataframe for filtering the data according to time.
For time, t=0, i want to plot the graph, I am using matplotlib for this purpose and also I am using igraph for the algorithms.
However, if I have n edges it is using 2*n nodes when nodes are few. When I try to take only the unique vertices, it is showing the error vertex id invalid and if I let the code take 2*n nodes then it is taking the vertices not even there in the time stamp. The graph formed is not meaningful as well

Comment: Recommend you also look into nodex package, and see its tutorials, and existing Q&A on SO.

Comment: But is there anything I could do to modify this only. Or could you tell me what is the problem?

Comment: You need to post an MCVE ([mcve]) example with a snippet of code and data that reproduces your problem. Also an image of your wrong plot. I can't answer this one but if you do that then other people should be able to find your issue.